# H is normal in G and H is not equal to <e>, then the intersection of H and C(G) is not equal to e

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a finite p-group, $H \lhd G$ and $H \neq <e>$, then $H \cap C(G) \neq <e>$. Hint: Use the idea of the proof of Therorem 47. Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation, what is $H_{0}$?

Proof:
Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation, then the fixed points

$$H_{G}= \{h \in H | ghg^{-1}, \forall g \in G\}= H \cap C(G)$$

Given that $G$ is a p-group, then $|H_{G}| \equiv |H| \equiv 0\pmod p\;$.  $|H_{G}| \geq e$. So $|H_{0}| \geq e$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is..if I understand correctly your notation. This much is true for any nilpotent group...and I think the notation $\;Z(G)\;$ is much more common for the group's center.

Comment: Oh ok great. Well I don't want to change it to Z(G) because that is how the question has it set up

Comment: I'm confused by the notation for $H_G$. Do you mean
$$ H_G = \{ ghg^{-1} : h\in H, g\in G\} ?$$

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. I just didn't write it in a good order.